# ssh TOTP connection with jump host forwarding

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-agent

How can I simplify this?
Perhaps using agent forwarding?

I have an SSH jump host with 2FA via TOTP x2 and a machine which uses 2FA as well(jump host and machine):

```
ssh myuser@host.corp.com -L 22222:my_machine.corp.com:22
# requires password + 2FA TOTP code
ssh myuser@localhost -p 22222
# requires password + 2FA TOTP code
```

How can I ideally simplify this (via SSH config or so) to simply call `ssh myhost` and then if needed be asked for the 2FA and password 2x - but not having to connect 2x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ProxyJump`  option of the ssh client to achieve that:

`ssh -J myuser@host.corp.com my_machine.corp.com`

or as an entry in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host my_machine.corp.com
  ProxyJump myuser@host.corp.com
```

Comment: I experimented with it earlier today - but somehow got a too many failed attempt error this way

Comment: I've not experimented with 2FA on ssh. I there a possiblity for you to use private/public key authentication instead ? I guess the prompt for 2FA can be messing with tunneling/ProxyJump