# SSH Remote command

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to execute a command from Server 1 through server 2 on a machine that's on the outside world is this possible via ssh tunnel forwarding? I made a little drawing as an example.

[image]

I've tried it with

```
ssh -L PORT:IP:PORT user@remotemachine "hostname"
```

When i try this i get the wrong hostname back

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssh TOTP connection with jump host forwarding](https://serverfault.com/questions/1082943/ssh-totp-connection-with-jump-host-forwarding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProxyJump function of SSH should be able to do what you need. Basically your server 2 would be the jump station to reach your server 3.
You have a good article available on redhat's website : https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue!